# How to convert Git commits to an Ubuntu patch request?

Tags: package-management, git

After following the [official guide for fixing a bug in Ubuntu](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/fixing-a-bug.html) I'm stuck at how to actually submit some existing work (in the form of local Git commits on an "ubuntu/devel" branch for a "main" pool* package). The guide seems to assume familiarity with Quilt and Debian packaging tools+infrastructure, since the first command to start actual work, `edit-patch 99-new-patch`, fails with

> No patchsystem detected, cannot create new patch (no dpatch/quilt/cdbs?)

which [seems to be misleading](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1837198.html). It also seems pretty complicated to map to version control systems ([1](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/11/18/4-tips-to-maintain-a-3-0-quilt-debian-source-package-in-a-vcs/), [2](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/piki/development/debian_packages_in_git/), [3](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopTeam/git)).

So: **Is there a complete and straightforward set of steps to submitting some Git commits for review?**

* Is "pool" the right name? None of `apt`, `apt-cache` or `dpkg` seem to tell.

Comment: Are you asking for a Stable Release Update (SRU)? Or are you just testing right now? Is there a Bug Report at Launchpad? At  Debian?

Comment: What even is an SRU? I'm not even sure what you mean by "testing." If you mean checking how updates work, then no. I have a fix for the "base-files" package which could be followed by a bunch of cleanup (ShellCheck and the like) if I could just unscramble the patch process.

Comment: Is the package in main, universe, multiverse, or someplace else?

Comment: Did you install the 'quilt' package? It will provide a modern patchsystem for patching tools to use.

Comment: @user535733 I expect it's in main since it's the base for every Ubuntu installation. I did install Quilt, but looking at the command reference it's not exactly obvious how my ten commits should be converted into two changesets. There seems to be weirdness like `quilt edit` which I really, really hope I don't have to use for every file I want to edit.

Comment: For packages in the 'main' pocket, It may not be necessary to create a patch. Most of those packages will be rebuilt by Debian (might need to ping the maintainer), then automatically merged into the next release of Ubuntu. We try to minimize the number of Ubuntu-specific patches by recommending folks push fixes upstream. Seems like your fix is already in the right place. Or...are you perhaps talking about backporting a fix to a current release of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are saying. "it may not be necessary to create a patch" - how else is it going to get fixed? Or is it not called a "patch" in Debian? "Seems like your fix is already in the right place." What do you mean? I've downloaded the *Ubuntu* sources, fixed and committed locally, and now I'm stumped. It's a *new* fix.

Comment: @user535733 It looks like your answer is "no", because I keep hearing new jargon and a rabbit hole of special cases, and still not understanding the first questions you asked. I've tried to update my question to integrate most of my answers.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have misunderstood. Use the 'quilt' package to fix the specific error you encountered with patching. There should be *three* bug trackers with open bugs about the issue (Ubuntu, Debian, and Upstream) - attach the patch to all three bug reports.

Comment: If I have to file three bug reports for a single fix I don't think it's worth the bother. Thank you for clearing up the situation! I'll probably just go back to Arch Linux, because this situation is broken.

Comment: The situation is the same in Arch. That's not *broken* -- that's a glimpse into how open-source communities work together. You CAN merely attach the patch to the Ubuntu bug tracker (at Launchpad.net.) Be prepared for an Ubuntu developer to ask you nicely to push the patch upstream.

Comment: If you are saying that you are sure NOBODY has filed a bug report, then file just one...upstream.